# Unable to validate role in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4.1.0.RELEASE with Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE.

I got following error please suggest me.

My URL pattern:

```xml
 <intercept-url pattern="/AS/**" access="hasRole('AS')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/SA/**"  access="hasRole('SA')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/SE/**" access="hasRole('SE')"/>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'SE'
    org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
```

Comment: Can you provide details configuration ?

Comment: <intercept-url pattern="/AS/**" access="hasRole('AS')"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/SA/**"  access="hasRole('SA')"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/SE/**" access="hasRole('SE')"/>

Comment: Where you are setting the roles?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an exclamation mark like - access= "!hasRole('USER')"